# Broadcast Receiver and services

Tags: android

I'm working on an App where it will be receiving a lot of messages through GCM.

I created Broadcast Receiver that callas an intent like so

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MyIntentService.class.getName());
                startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
                setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            }
}
```

then MyIntentService will call a handler to save the message in the DB.

Everything is working fine, my question is this,  it ok to do what is shown above? I'm 2 months old in Android but the above looks like it will create a service every time there is a new message, for example if 20 GCM messages received at the same time then it means 20 services will start working.
Is my interpretation correct? if yes what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That is actually not the case and only one service will be started.
As stated by the Docs startWakefulService() performs a context.startService() which states that:

> If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running.

So basically a service will only be created if it does not already exist. The docs also state that the new intent will be delivered to the existing service calling its onStartCommand().

So yeah you should be fine doing it the way you are as its only using one service!

Docs:

[context.startService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))

[startWakefulService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html#startWakefulService(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))

Comment: In this case, can I make the service sticky? so that it will be there and will be receiving the message from the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Or is it better bind to it when receiving new message?

Answer (score 0):

If your MyIntentService is extending IntentService, then all you should have to do is release the wake lock that was being held using the following:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    // ADD YOUR GCM TO THE DB HERE, THEN RELEASE THE WAKE LOCK
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```

From the documentation:

> "the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work"

So from what I can gather, the service will stop itself after you place the GCM message into your database.

Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)